# C# regex exact length

Tags: c#, regex

I have a program, that has to output substrings of exact length using regexp.
But it outputs also substrings of a greater length, which match format.
input: a as asb, asd asdf  asdfg
expected output(with length = 3): asb asd
real output: asb asd asd asd

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace LR3_2
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void regPrint(String input, int count)
        {
            String regFormat = @"[a-zA-Z]{" + count.ToString() + "}";
            Regex reg = new Regex(regFormat);
            foreach (var regexMatch in reg.Matches(input))
            {
                Console.Write(regexMatch + " ");
            }

            //Match matchObj = reg.Match(input);
            //while (matchObj.Success)
            //{
            //    Console.Write(matchObj.Value + " ");
            //    matchObj = reg.Match(input, matchObj.Index + 1);
            //}
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String input = " ";
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter string:");
            //input = Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter count:");
            //int count = Console.Read();

            input += "a as asb, asd asdf  asdfg";
            int count = 3;
            regPrint(input, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `\b`, which means "at beginning or end of a word", to your expression, for example:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b
```

In your code you should do the following:

```
String regFormat = @"\b[a-zA-Z]{" + count.ToString() + @"}\b";
```

To test regular expression before coding your own test program, you can use tools like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) or [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/). They actually help you writing the expression and test it.

Comment: if i set specific number(like 3) - it works. But it doesn't work with count.ToString()

Comment: Yes, this was an example for the case of 3, then you have to create the expression concatenating strings like you were doing before. See updated answer.

Comment: @UnknitSplash: it does work with `count.ToString()`. How is your code? Did you by any chance forget the `@` before the last part of the string?